# How to test that an MVC action is only accessible via HTTP POST?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

I am using MvcContrib-TestHelper to test the routing on my app. I have an action which is restricted to HTTP POST only:

```
public TestController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Example()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And here is an example of a test that should fail:

```
[TestFixture]
public class RoutingTests
{
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Clear();
        Application.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestWithGet()
    {
        var route = "~/Test/Example".WithMethod(HttpVerbs.Get);
        route.ShouldMapTo(r => r.Example());
    }
}
```

However, the test passes! I've seen one other unanswered question (sorry, wrong link) where this was also raised, and it seems like the functionality is broken. What's a better way to test that this route is accessible via POST only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
var controller = new HomeController();
var methodInfo = controller.GetType().GetMethod("MrthodName");
var attributes = methodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(ActionMethodSelectorAttribute), true).Cast<ActionMethodSelectorAttribute>().ToList();
```

attributes - this is list accept verbs

Comment: Does this work regardless of the difference between [HttpPost] and [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]?

Comment: check it out. I'm almost 90% sure that this is the same

Comment: Given it a test, it sees AcceptVerbsAttribute and HttpPostAttribute separately. Reflection is probably as near as I'll get though - I'll see if there's anything that lives closer to the actual way these are parsed for routing information, and if not, I'll accept this answer shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are just trying to test the ASP.NET MVC framework there. I dont think that such test will bring value...

Comment: he could be ensuring certain actions have only available through post.

Comment: yes, you are right. however it depends on the context. and i think that in most cases such tests a not relevant

Comment: I understand what you mean, and testing for the presence of the attribute should be enough. However, I was just assuming that as `WithMethod(HttpVerbs)` exists within MvcContrib for testing routing, the verbs passed would have some kind of use.